# Unable to install Pillow for Django App using Terminal on Namecheap Shared hosting

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, namecheap

I was going to deploy my Django App on Namecheap shared hosting. My app needs Pillow to be able to run perfectly. But while installing pillow using `pip install Pillow` in Namecheap's Terminal, I get the error. I installed Django and other libraries successfully. But while installing Pillow, it gives me this error.

```
Collecting Pillow==8.4.0
  Using cached Pillow-8.4.0.tar.gz (49.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-vyxwq5up
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/
  Complete output (143 lines):
  /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  building 'PIL._imaging' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/libImaging
  building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
  /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result-Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac -I/home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmorph.o
  unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
  unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
  unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
  Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
Installing collected packages: Pillow
    Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize,'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-j3nzm_7c/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include/site/python3.8/Pillow
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/
    Complete output (143 lines):
    /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
    building 'PIL._imagingtk' extension
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac -I/home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingft.o
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/libImaging
    building 'PIL._imagingmath' extension
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac -I/home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmath.o
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION="8.4.0" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac -I/home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imaging.o
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/Tk
    building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac -I/home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingtk.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingtk.o
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac -I/home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmorph.o
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]= '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u2_5lsia/pillow_aabaeed7df664fd985a82d84f11f5eac/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-j3nzm_7c/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/include/site/python3.8/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried to upgrade pip, but that did not solve the issue. Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

pip install pillow==8.0.0 solved my problem. trying to install the latest version will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that should help (or whatever is an analog of "sudo apt install build-essential"):

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ make
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to do it, but it has proved time and again to be effective and easy workaround.

This method is for Namecheap shared hosting as the question indicated.
Assuming you already Installed pillow Inside your local environment. Select all pillow file inside the "site-packages" folder and zip compress them as a copy.

Now go back to your namecheap hosting file manager and go to the location (current projects site-packages inside the virtual environment)
/home/abduxdcv/virtualenv/iffi-store-app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages

(/home/shared-hosting-name/virtualenv/name-of-current-app/python-version/lib/python3.version/site-packages)

Upload the zipped PILLOW files and extract them into the site-packages folder you're already in (Note location above)

Everything should work fine now. Confirm by running python3 manage.py makemigrations and migrate respectively. Since your projects uses models.ImageField() an error should occur if PILLOW isn't working. If no errors continue with your project.

Unfortunately I can't include screenshots of the said step because of reputation. I will look for workaround.

Step1: Zip compress installed pillow files locally.

Step 2: Upload the zipped PILLOW files and extract into Namecheap hosted target projects site-packages inside the virtual environment.

PS:
This is a quick answer, apologies for any bad construction.

Update: link to github gist [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Mgregchi/edd89f3d4c0896ed818d715354234595)